# Image of open set under a real analytic map is Borel?

Tags: descriptive-set-theory

It is well known that the image of a Borel set under a continuous map may fail to be Borel. [This MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/415759/is-the-image-of-a-borel-subset-of-0-1-under-a-differentiable-map-still-a-bor/416907#416907) shows even $C^\infty$ maps may fail to map Borel sets to Borel sets.

I want to ask whether a positive result can be obtained under some very strong conditions.

> Specifically, let $M$ and $N$ be real analytic manifolds and let $f$ be a real analytic map from $M$ to $N$. Must $f(U)$ be a Borel set for any open subset of $M$?

The specific case that I care about is $M=O_d(\mathbb R)\times \text{Diag}_d(\mathbb R_{\ge 0})\times O_d(\mathbb R)$ and $f(L,D,R)=LDR$. This map, which arises in studying singular value decomposition, is well-behaved for $D$ that have distinct diagonal entries.
If there is a positive answer to my question, it will follow that the map $f$ satisfies the conditions of the Kuratowski/Ryll-Nardzewski measurable selection theorem, so that there are measurable functions $L\colon M_d(\mathbb R)\to O_d(\mathbb R)$, $D\colon M_d(\mathbb R)\to \text{Diag}_d(\mathbb R_{\ge 0})$ and $R\colon M_d(\mathbb R)\to O_d(\mathbb R)$ such that $A=L(A)D(A)R(A)$. I believe this result is already known (it is stated in a paper of M.S. Raghunathan) and I think I see how to obtain a measurable SVD with more or less bare hands methods, but I am interested in whether it can be obtained from general machinery.

In the specific case, the map $f$ defined above is locally open at points of $M$ where the entries of the diagonal matrix are distinct, but fails to be locally open at $(I,I,I)$ for example. These points are the key source of difficulty in the problem.

Comment: In your particular case the life is trivial because on your manifolds open is a countable union of compact and a continuous image of compact is compact.

Comment: We can't use open sets, as indicated by fedja. We can find a $G_\delta$ subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ whose projection onto $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a complete analytic set (other sense, obviously), and therefore not Borel. The projection map $\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is linear, and therefore real-analytic. I think this is essentially the original non-Borel subset.

Comment: Thanks @Fedja. This is very helpful.